# How do I link Anaconda3 libraries python?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I'm trying to `import panda`s into a script.

I'm using `anaconda`, I've already edited the `python` path to the executable file in the `anaconda3` folder.

I'm just not able to access any of the libraries I've downloaded (`matplotlib`, `pandas`, `numpy`)

Just looking for some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how did you exactly edited the python path? As Baran Karakus mentioned. If you use anaconda, you shouldn't need to specify python path and Conda handle it. If you exported the path anywhere in your shell rc file, you can removed it. Also, what OS you are on? Did you use a conda environment or a default one.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this in the original message. I'm using VS Code. Does that change anything?

Comment: It does in the sense that IDE/Editor tried to choose python path for you. For example in Pycharm you can specify where is your environment as well as the root path of the project. Similar in VSCode, but I am afraid I am not too experience in that. But essentially you use the command Python:select interpreter. And choose the correct condo environment.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t edit the PYTHONPATH or PATH yourself. Let Anaconda handle it for you. Switch to the appropriate conda environment using conda at the command-line and try importing those modules again.